# Angular4 disable button if json-schema-form is not valid

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-schema-form

I have a registration form built with more than 1 json-schema-form.

I have the basic details where the participant must fill in, and I have 2 partial forms that are dynamic. These 2 forms will only appear if the admin has set the parameters for the form.

```
     <div class="registration-form">
       <json-schema-form [model]="participantEventInfo" [schema]="json_custom_form" (isValid)="isEventFormValid($event)" (onChanges)="updateParticipantEventInfo($event)"></json-schema-form>
       <json-schema-form [model]="participantTixInfo" [schema]="json_tix_custom_form" (onChanges)="updateParticipantTixInfo($event)" (isValid)="isTixFormValid($event)"></json-schema-form>
       <button type="submit" [disabled]="!participantEventInfo.isValid && !participantTixInfo.isValid" (click)="updateEventandTixInfoRegistration()">Update</button>
     </div>
```

So now I have 2 json-schema-form, one for event info, one for ticket info. I would like to disable th submit button, so in my submit button, I want to disable the buttton is either of the schema form is not filled up. However, based on my code, even if I fill in all the form fields, the button is always disabled. Am I doing the disabling part correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your component.ts code as well.

Answer (score 0):

try checking these two and disable button

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!checkForm()" click)="updateEventandTixInfoRegistration()">Update</button>

checkForm(){
    if(document.forms[0].checkValidity() && document.forms[1].checkValidity()){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```